# Opennms - Physical interface update on Cisco Switches

Tags: cisco, switch, snmp, opennms

I'm using opennms version  16.0.2-1 on ubuntu server 14.04 LTS.

I'm configuring some cisco switches to send traps to openms.
The traps are notified to events in opennms,  if i put a physical interface down on a switch, I receive the alarm like " Agent Interface Down (linkDown Trap) on interface index:2; ifDescr: FastEthernet1/1; ifName:Fa1/1; ifAlias:"Link to ESW1-ariannas2".

If i check physical interface sections opennms says that interface is up.
Why opennms doesn't update status interface.
To update the status interface I have to manually rescan the node.
Can you help me please?

Thank you very much